# PB2 PORTER - BETTER TASTE?

Tags: all-grain, porter, chocolate, flavoring

I recently made a 5 gallon All Grain Porter and added 13oz of Choc. PB2 at the last 10 minutes of the boil.  Though the flavors were there it was extremely light and would like to get more of a PB taste.

Would it be smarter to add it as a whirlpool or perhaps as a vodka extract in the secondary?

Any help would be great.

Comment: That sounds like it would taste awesome!

Comment: it does - but I am trying to get more PB flavor into it without adding a ton more PB2

Answer (score 1):

Yeast absorb a lot of those extra tastes from stuff you add to the kettle. If you want to get the maximum taste of a spice or alike, add it as a tincture at bottling time. And even then it may fade over a few months.

Btw make sure to add extra carapils or flakes to the mash: oils in chocolate may render the poor head.

Comment: i put about 1.25# flaked oats in the mash which really helps with the head retention.  So if I made a tincture (I would assume vodka with the PB2 is best) when would you add it into the boil?

Comment: I would not add it to the _boil_, but rather to the bottles at bottling time. Take, say, 100 ml or beer and add as many drops or ml (count them!) of the tincture as you need to get the taste that's right for you. Scale it to either your batch size or each bottle and put the tincture in (if you put the tincture in each bottle, you can then make a part of the batch without the flavoring and later compare how much taste you've got from the addition. Make sure to journal all quantities, that's how you learn)

Comment: how do you usually create a tinture?

Comment: What I did with spices before - put a good load of them into a hermetic jar with vodka, with proportion to get approx 50-100 ml of vodka after I take spices away and squeeze them. Guess something similar should work for choc chips?

Answer (score 0):

In my book "Experimental Homebrewing" we recommend blending the jar of PB2 with 6 oz. of 150 proof neutral grain spirits on brew day and storing it in a jar until the beer has fermented.  When primary has finished, add the PB slurry to a sanitized container and rack the beer onto it.  Let it age for a week, than rack and package the beer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help Denny - looking forward to checking out your book once released (and get you to sign it...haha)

Comment: Congrats on the book... the preview on Amazon looks interesting and I'll be ordering it soon.